# "list indices must be integers or slices, not [custom class]" but I'm specifying an int class instance?

Tags: python, class

I have a custom class defined like so:

```
class points:
    def __init__(self, x=0, h=0, l=0):
        self.x = x
        self.h = h
        self.l = l #bool location, 0 for start point, 1 for endpoint
```

Further in my code, I successfully build a list of these `points`, and the error comes when I attempt the following conditional:

```
for i in points_list:
    if (sorted_points[i].l == 0):
```

Python thinks that `sorted_points[i].l` isn't an integer or slice (it thinks it's a `points` object), but the only thing it can be is an integer (I even try printing out the list of `sorted_points` `l` values, and they are all 1 or 0), so I am very confused.

Comment: You are using `i` as an index for `sorted_points`. What do you think `i` is?

Comment: **Python thinks that sorted_points[i].l isn't an integer or slice**. No, it thinks `i` isn't an integer or slice. `points_list` is a list of points, so `i` is a point.

Comment: Even if `i` is an index, why would you be looping through one list and using that as indexes into a different list, unless the two lists are correlated in parallel. But `sorted_points` is presumably ordered differently from `points_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for el in my_list` syntax iterates over the elements of `my_list`.
Look:

```
class A:
    pass

l = [A(), A(), A()]
for el in l:
    print(type(el)) # <class '__main__.A'>
```

So in your case you should use your `i` as instance of point.

```
for i in points_list:
    if i.l == 0: # if it's boolean, you should even write if not i.l
        ...
```

If you want to iterate over indexes, use `range`

```
for i in range(len(points_list)):
    if not sorted_points[i].l:
        ...
```